# Get and MD5 hash of an UTF-8 encoded string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding, utf-8, etl

As far as I understand SQL Server offers two datatypes for storing strings - VARCHAR for 8-bit ISO encodings and NVARCHAR for UTF-16. The problem is that I need to retrieve the MD5 of an UTF-8 encoded string just with a SELECT.

This is required so I don't read any personal data from the server for storing in the Warehouse, but I am still getting an unique value for each, let's say, email address, to match with the data coming from other sources which use proper UTF-8.

Let's say we've got following string:

'*SIRIO SOCIETÀ COOPERATIVA*' stored in a VARCHAR column named "nomeCompleto" in row no 1.

```
SELECT hashbytes('MD5',nomeCompleto) FROM sampleTable WHERE row_id = 1
```

returns following bytes

```
0xF5F3DA4E538693D68C27F7B24948D348
```

In unicode:

```
SELECT hashbytes('MD5',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),nomeCompleto))
```

When I cast it to NVARCHAR i get:

```
0x7FDCB5E7E91D01177B124F1A5BE218B1
```

The problem is, that if the same string came from some API or another RDMBS, that uses UTF-8, and I md5-ed it, i would rather get:

```
0x27380195AA7488AE0CD5CD96A13932B3
```

How do I retrieve the third value from SQL server without writing custom functions etc?

Comment: Why use MD5, when it's deprecated?

Comment: Also [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: As for UTF-8 support, that was added in SQL Server 2019. If you must use UTF-8 within SQL Server, you need to be using 2019+.

Comment: @Larnu, not my choice. I have to align with what's been already done. This nvarchar without length is only for demostration purposes.

Comment: *"This nvarchar without length is only for demostration purposes."* Then, with respect, it's a poor demonstration. Using such bad practices in a demonstration is going to derail your question, as it's likely that we're going to assume that those bad practices are the reason you're code isn't working as you expect. There's a reason they are bad practices.

Comment: Corrected, but it's still irrelevant for the problem :)

Comment: Yes, I address the problem of using UTF-8 (in SQL Server) in my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905072/get-and-md5-hash-of-an-utf-8-encoded-string-in-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment118265122_66905072). You need SQL Server 2019+.

Comment: The assumption that SQL Server uses UTF-16 encoding for nvarchar columns is generally incorrect. Generally SQL Server will be using UCS-2 encoding for nchar/nvarchar/ntext columns, it will only use UTF-16 encoding if the current database's default collation is using one of the *_SC Supplementary Characters collation. See [Unicode Considerations and Supplementary Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#unicode-considerations)

Comment: `SELECT hashbytes('MD5', nomeCompleto COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2_UTF8) FROM sampleTable WHERE row_id = 1` obviously you need SQL2019 as mentioned

Comment: @Charlieface, I assume that works only with SQL Server 2019, right?

Comment: ... is exactly what I said. Your other option is a SQLCLR function in C#

Comment: I cannot use C#. I can only SELECT data from the server. There is a UDF function that does it, but with read only permissions I cannot use it.

Comment: *"There is a UDF function that does it, but with read only permissions I cannot use it."* If you're on SQL Server 2019 yes. If not, no. Again, if you must have UTF-8 support natively you ***need*** to upgrade to 2019.

Comment: If you really want MD5 there is an extended stored procedure avalable I've used previously on 2008R2 [see here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5963/MD5-Hash-SQL-Server-Extended-Stored-Procedure)

Comment: The problem isn't MD5 here, @Stu , it's UTF-8. SQL Server (even 2019) still allows hashing to MD5; just that most recent versions will raise a deprecation warning.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. Higlhy appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following (SQL Server 2019):

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', CAST (N'SIRIO SOCIETÀ COOPERATIVA' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 AS varchar(4000)))
```

=> 0x93E20A6CB6CE6F8945123D6ADC75E30C

Try MD5 Online : https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/md5.html

Comment: You need to test with characters that have a multi-byte encoding only in UTF-8.

Comment: The above is just a specific example, it should be changed according to the intended use.

Comment: Right but use, for example, the euro symbol in your answer.

Comment: Hi @David Browne - Microsoft
In this case, we can still use Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8.
The euro symbo : €  : 0xBCA53FDE466A76B7BEE3E18997E94A7A

Comment: Right.  I think your answer is correct, it's not obvious because the example you gave uses all characters that have single-byte encodings in most varchar collations.